# Запрет закрытия главного окна в pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt

Всем привет!
Как в pyqt сделать так, чтоб окно не закрывалось при нажатии на крестик?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два способа решить эту проблему. Первый - это выключить саму кнопку, передав в метод `setWindowFlags()` соответствующий набор флагов:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget,
    QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox)

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = u'Тест'
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 140
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Второй - игнорировать событие закрытия окна:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget,
    QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox)

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = u'Тест'
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 140
        self.initUI()
        self._closable = False

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.button = QPushButton(u'Закрыть', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, evnt):
        if self._closable:
            super(App, self).closeEvent(evnt)
        else:
            evnt.ignore()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        self._closable = True
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А зачем использовать `@pyqtSlot()` если можно и без этого по сигналу вызывать?

Comment: @gil9red можно и без него. Он только оптимизирует вызовы. Я его рефлекторно навешиваю.

Comment: спасибо, попробую